# Как добавить в автозагрузку и пространство имен laravel библиотеки?

Tags: php, сокет, framework, laravel, ratchet

**Необходимо в конкретном случае добавить библиотеку Ratchet**
*для поддержки чата на сокетах*

- В какую директорию положить?
- Куда подключить пространства имен?
- Как добавить в автолоадер

Answer (score 1):

Создаёшь папку в `app/{название}`
Переходишь в `app/start/global.php`
И редактриуешь следущее:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/{название папки}',

));
```

Потом сможешь использовать везде этот класс.